# How to inject external javascript file to the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I need to inject some external js widget to the page. How to do that with the manifest 3? Seems like `chrome.scripting` doesn't accept links. I could've easily done that with manifest v2 but manifest v3 forbids any other approaches other than using `chrome.scripting`. I can't move to manifest v2 because it'll get deprecated after the new year.

Answer (score 1):

Screw the security! They completely forbade remotely hosted code:

> A key security improvement in MV3 is that extensions can't load remote
> code like JavaScript or Wasm files. This lets us more reliably and
> efficiently review the safe behavior of extensions when they're
> submitted to the Chrome Web Store. Specifically, all logic must be
> included in the extension's package.
> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code

So that's impossible to inject any code from a link.

Comment: This makes me so angry!